# Plotting multiple rater: restriction on number of panels

Tags: r, raster

Is there a restriction on how many raster I can plot using using the plot function? For e.g

```
library(raster)
mystack <- stack()

for(i in 1:25){

  df <- data.frame( x = rep( 0:1, each=2 ),
                    y = rep( 0:1,  2),
                    l = rnorm( 4 ))
  dfr <- rasterFromXYZ(df)  
  mystack <- stack(mystack, dfr)
  }

plot(mystack)
```

It plots only 16 plots no matter how many iterations I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, from `` ?`plot,Raster,ANY-method` ``:

> ## S4 method for signature 'Raster,ANY' plot(x, y, maxpixels=500000, col, alpha=NULL,    colNA=NA, add=FALSE, ext=NULL, useRaster=TRUE,
>   interpolate=FALSE,     addfun=NULL, nc, nr, maxnl=16, main, npretty=0,
>   ...)

Notice `maxnl = 16`. All you need is to change that to the desired number of layers:

```
plot(mystack, maxnl=25)
```